# Wordpress Background Audio - Continous AutoPlay

Tags: plugins, php, audio

I'm kinda of a newbie , but know my way around a bit in Wordpress to code things in place.

I would like to know if you happen to know how to create a continous audio play in the background of the website , *including* the time a visitor clicks on different pages, posts or sections of the website.

I have tried coding the audio into  but that doesn't solve the problem because when the page reloads, the audio starts over and I don't want that.

Coding , plugins ... whatever does the job.

I know that this is not quite ok for the visitor , but please bear with me.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an idea or example how would that work _in general_ for starters? The generic implementation of something like this would come before and won't really _depend_ on WordPress specifics.

Comment: Hi. Yes, you are right . But this applies to a Wordpress website and this is why I mentioned it.To be frank, I never was interested in a general , academic explanation for this. I just need to have this implemented for a friend. It's more practical in nature.

Comment: Please note that we define in scope here as _specific_ to WordPress development, not simply in its _context_. See [what topics can I ask about here?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to add a comment yet, I read on [another website](http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2010/08/28/play-music-continuously-across-page-loads/) that someone used http://scmplayer.net/ as an alternative to frames/popups which seems to be a little script you can generate and then use on both non-WordPress and WordPress sites (since it just needs to be inserted after the `<body>` tag).

Or you can self-host the script ([source](https://github.com/cshum/SCM-Music-Player/)) but either way, you should be aware that there are [reported issues](https://github.com/cshum/SCM-Music-Player/issues) with SCM Player at the moment.

So without commenting on whether this script is a good or bad approach, how you apply it to your WordPress install will differ depending on your theme and if you prefer to self-host etc.  But it will involve editing of theme files; whether this is your child theme or adding the relevant scripts to your theme's functions.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment / answer . It really helped and I did implement it quite easy indeed. Nothing major, just added the script to the template files and followed the setup wizard and added the script into header.php of my theme. Simple and effective. Thank you for that :)

Comment: It has although a small 1 sec glitch when I click on another page , but it will do the job for now

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :) Am glad it worked for you and its good to know of its issues in practice.